# indexed array foreach shorthand

Tags: php, loops, language-agnostic, programming-languages

Data:

```
$players = array(
    new Player('psycketom'),
    new Player('stackexchanger'),
    new Player('max')
);
```

Usually, in order to get something out of every object within array, we have to use [for](/questions/tagged/for) / [foreach](/questions/tagged/foreach).

```
foreach ($players as $player)
{
    var_dump( $player->score );
}
```

But, since it's a repetitive task, **is there a way to shortcut it to something along these imaginary lines(?)**:

```
var_dump( every( $players )->score );

every( $players )->score += 40;
```

Since I have not seen such a feature for [php](/questions/tagged/php), **is there a way to implement it?**

I have asked the question using [php](/questions/tagged/php) as main language, but the [language-agnostic](/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) and [programming-languages](/questions/tagged/programming-languages) stand for the second part of the question: **what languages support such or at least similar shorthand?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you are correct that PHP does not support this "out of the box" (except kinda, see below). The first language I know of that does is Objective-C (well, at least the CoreFoundation library). NSArrays and other sets have methods to (in one line) instruct that [a given method should be executed on all members](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABCBHFG); and even more cool (to me, at least) is the concept of "keypaths" and the [support that NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCIBCDJ) and others has for them. An example; lets say you have an array of "people" who each have a parent, who in turn have a "name":

```
arrayOfNames = [peopleArray valueForKeyPath:"parent.name"];
```

arrayOfNames is now an array of all the parents' names.

The closest thing PHP has is [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), which you can use together with anonymous functions to very quickly whip something together.

**edit** anecdotal as it may be, one should remember that loop structures don't *need* their curly-braces if there is only one statement to execute; so any fancier solutions need to compete with this:

```
foreach($players as $p) $p->score += 40;
```

And I'll mention a *deeper* solution for those OOP fans out there... If you work with collection objects instead of arrays, the world is your oyster with stuff like this. The simplest concept that comes to mind is php's magic `__call()` method. How simple to iterate over your members and make that call for your users? For more controll, you can implement a few different strategies for iteration (one for transforms, one for filters, etc. Difference being what gets returned, essentially). So in theory you could create a few different iterator classes, and in your "main" collection class implement a couple methods to get one of them, which will be pre-initialized with the contents:

```
$players->transform()->addScore(40);
```

where transform() returns an instance of your "don't return the array" iterator, which uses the __call() technique.

The sky starts to open up at this point, and you can start to build filter iterators which take predicates and return another collection of a subset of the objects, and syntax like this is possible:

```
// send flyer to all parents with valid email address
$parentsPredicate = new Predicate('email');
$players->filteredByPredicate($parentsPredicate)->each()->email($fyler_email_body);
```

Comment: "NSArrays and other sets have **methods**..." any references on those methods?

Comment: I added links to the answer. If you are into this at a conceptual level, you might also really dig their key-value coding in general, it's very deeply integrated all over the place, and then their implementation of "key-value-observing" (not iOS yet) adds power to the flexibility. One of my favorite reads on the Cocoa implementations of all this (and OOP/Design patterns in general): http://www.amazon.com/Cocoa-Design-Patterns-Erik-Buck/dp/0321535022/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1346397985&sr=1-1&keywords=cocoa+design+patterns

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
var_dump(array_map(function($el){return $el->score;}, $players));

array_walk($players, function($el) {$el->score += 40;});
```

Comment: Well yes, but it's not as expressive as it could be.